# jQuery - get value of checked checkbox that has a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'd like to get the `value` of the checked checkbox that has the `radioListMode` class:

```
<label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" class="radioListMode" value="cards" checked>Cards
</label>
<label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" class="radioListMode" value="pins">Pins
</label>
```

From this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292778/use-jquery-to-get-values-of-selected-checkboxes), this is what I have tried and it is `undefined`:

```
console.log($('input[class="radioListMode"]:checked').value);
```

I do not wish to add a `name` because the value of this checkbox is only used for layout selection, not any data input.

Comment: Have you tried $('input.class="radioListMode"]:checked').val()

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't add an ID. The extra amount of data sent would not make much of a difference in bandwidth costs unless you were processing billions (with a b) of users a month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you seem to be using jQuery, stick with it:

```
$('input.radioListMode:checked').val();
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that `input.radioListMode` would work, is that just a shortcut for the square bracket notation with classes?

Comment: Yes they do the same thing. The square bracket notation is not used very often in my experience.  Much more common to see .className and #id

Answer (score 2):

Use `.val()` property

`$('input[class="radioListMode"]:checked').val()`

Answer (score 1):

`.value` is not a jQuery function, instead use `.val()` like following :

```
console.log($('input[class="radioListMode"]:checked').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".yourClassName:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
     console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```