# input value from form into array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, post

i have this code :

```
<?php 
   $no=0;
   foreach($gejala as $g){ 
   $no++;?>
   <tr>

   <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $g->gejala; ?></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="gejala<?php echo $no;?>" value="<?php echo $no;?>"?></td>

   </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

i need to get all selected checkbox value from my input into an array so i can use it to get value from my database, using this query

```
SELECT * FROM gejala WHERE id_gejala IN (array) AND id_penyakit = '1'
```

Comment: If you are using jquery just follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11292798/6582942

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the values then you should give your checkboxes the same name, this way you'll get them in an array.