# How to get checkbox value and store in a array

Tags: javascript

In my project, I want to instor checkbox value to array.

Here is my code:

```
$('#fpdId').click(function(){
    var files = new Array();

    //xzyId is table id.
    $('#xzyId tbody tr  input:checkbox').each(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
      files.push(this.value);
      }
    });

    console.log(files);
 });

  <input type="button" id="fpdId" value="filePack">
```

My html table has three rows and each row has three tds

Here is table code:

```
 <table border=1px class="xzy" id="xzyId" style="width:100%">
        <colgroup>
          <col style="width:10%">
          <col style="width:80%">
          <col style="width:10%">
        </colgroup>
       <tbody>
        <tr> 
           <td ><input type="checkbox" value="x" >1</td>
           <td >Stack</td>
           <td >John</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
           <td ><input type="checkbox" value="y" >2</td>
           <td >Stack</td>
           <td >Sansa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
           <td ><input type="checkbox" value="z" >3</td>
           <td >Stack</td>
           <td >Aya</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
```

But unlucky, the array is empty, What is wrong?

Comment: can you add html part of that table,, with form and checkboxes?

Comment: did you even tried searching already? here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292778/use-jquery-to-get-values-of-selected-checkboxes

Comment: You have given code in jquery but the tag is javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be helpful to you

I have changed.

```
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  }
```

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
$('#fpdId').click(function(){
    var files = new Array();

    //xzyId is table id.
    $('#xzyId tbody tr  input:checkbox').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      files.push(this.value);
      }
    });

    console.log(files);
 });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1px class="xzy" id="xzyId" style="width:100%">
    <colgroup>
      <col style="width:10%">
      <col style="width:80%">
      <col style="width:10%">
    </colgroup>
   <tbody>
    <tr> 
       <td ><input type="checkbox" value="x" >1</td>
       <td >Stack</td>
       <td >John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
       <td ><input type="checkbox" value="y" >2</td>
       <td >Stack</td>
       <td >Sansa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
       <td ><input type="checkbox" value="z" >3</td>
       <td >Stack</td>
       <td >Aya</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>

 <input type="button" id="fpdId" value="filePack">
```

Comment: This is jquery, the tag is javascript

Comment: Yah! your correct @Omkaar.k but inside of the code in above question is using jquery right