# Jquery display checkbox switch value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pull value of checkbox based on switch selected. How can I pull value of selected switch?

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8jgbfp5d/1/)

```css
input[type=checkbox]{
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
}

label {
 cursor: pointer;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
 background: grey;
 display: block;
 border-radius: 100px;
 position: relative;
}

label:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 left: 5px;
 width: 90px;
 height: 90px;
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 90px;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

input:checked + label {
 background: #bada55;
}

input:checked + label:after {
 left: calc(100% - 5px);
 transform: translateX(-100%);
}

label:active:after {
 width: 130px;
}

// centering
body {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" /><label for="switch">Toggle</label>
```

Edit:
This is different from reading a checkbox value. This is a label.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use jQuery to get values of selected checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292778/use-jquery-to-get-values-of-selected-checkboxes)

Comment: The question I have is a Switch checkbox instead of normal checkbox.

Comment: no, you have a checkbox that's styled as a switch.  The HTML renders as a checkbox.  jQuery / JS work on HTML DOM elements, and not their rendering after CSS is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Going with your fiddle, here’s an example with the answer included.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" onchange="document.getElementById('state').innerHTML=(this.checked?'on':'off');"/><label for="switch">Toggle</label>
```

Ergo, query the input’s checked property.