# Cannot get all values of selected checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the values of the checkboxes that are checked but I can only get one value to show up. I'm using jQuery to get different types of values. I am also able to get the values of radio buttons, but not all the values of the checked checkboxes. So let's say the user selects Pasta and Ceasar, I would like the user to see Salads selected: Pasta and Ceasar.I just started learning JS so i'm not really sure how to do it. 
Thanks!

```js
function summarizePackages() {
            //get inside the div that's holding the buttons
            var packages = $('.expander-content > .item');
            var summary = '';

            packages.each(function(index, pkg) {
                pkg = $(pkg);

                var name = $.trim(pkg.find('h3').text());
                var entree = pkg.find('[name^="Entree Item"]:checked');
                var salad = pkg.find('[name^="Salad Name"]:checked');
                var delivery = pkg.find('[name^="Delivery Time"]:checked');
                var hasOrder = pkg.find('input:checked').length > 0;

                if (hasOrder) {
                    summary += 'Name of package: <b>' + name + '</b>';
                    summary += '<br>';

                    if (entree.length) {
                        summary += 'Entree selected: <b>' + entree.val() + '</b>' + '<br>';
                    }
                    if (salad.length) {
                        summary += 'Salads selected: <b>' + salad.val() + '</b>' + '<br>';
                    }
                    if (delivery.length) {
                        summary += 'Delivery selected: <b>' + delivery.val() + '</b>' + '<br>';
                    }
                    summary += '--------------------';
                    summary += '<br>';
                }
            });

            return summary;
        }

        $('#reviewOrder input').on('change', function() {
            var summary = summarizePackages();
            $('#output').html(summary);
        });

        //make sure the user only selects two checkboxes
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[class='onlyTwo']").change(function () {
        var maxAllowed = 2;
        var cnt = $("input[class='onlyTwo']:checked").length;
        if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
            $(this).prop("checked", "");
            alert('You can only select ' + maxAllowed + ' salads!');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Order Form</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="reviewOrder">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Suite Packages</legend>
            <h6 class="fieldset_description">Please choose your delivery time for each item.<br> 12 order minimum</h6>
            <div class="expander">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="expander-trigger expander-hidden">View Suite Packages</a>
                <div class="expander-content">
                    <div class="item">
                        <h3 class="product-title">FIRST DOWN PACKAGE<small> $15.50ea</small></h3>
                        <p>Includes: Peanuts and pretzels. Your choice of Mustang Dogs served with mustard, ketchup, white onions, relish and buns, or the Nacho Station served with grilled chicken, jalapenos, olives, onions, guacamole, sour cream and nacho cheese. Your choice of 2 salads from pasta salad, Caesar salad or seasonal fruit salad. Cookie and brownie platter.</p>
                        <div class="entreesGroup">
                            <div>
                                <p>Entr&eacute;e (Choose One)</p>
                                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item 1" value="Mustang Hot Dog"> Mustang Hot Dog<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item 1" value="Nacho Station"> Nacho Station<br>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Salads (Choose Two)</p>
                                <input class="onlyTwo" type="checkbox" name="Salad Name 1" value="Ceasar"> Ceasar<br>
                                <input class="onlyTwo" type="checkbox" name="Salad Name 1" value="Pasta"> Pasta <br>
                                <input class="onlyTwo" type="checkbox" name="Salad Name 1" value="Seasonal Fruit Salad"> Seasonal Fruit Salad<br>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Choose Delivery Time</p>
                                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 1" value="Pre Game">Pre Game<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 1" value="Kick Off">Kick Off<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 1" value="Half Time">Half Time<br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p>How many?</p>
                        <input type="text" name="FIRST DOWN PACKAGE" value="0" maxlength="2" class="qty num-pallets-input" id="FIRST+DOWN+PACKAGE-mvp-num-pallets" style="margin-bottom:0" />
                        <p class="price-per-pallet"><small>* Price per guest: <span> 15.50</span></small></p>
                        <div class="row-total">
                            <input type="text" class="row-total-input" id="FIRST+DOWN+PACKAGE-mvp-row-total" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div>
                            <h3 class="product-title">FIELD GOAL PACKAGE<small> $20.00ea</small></h3>
                            <p>Peanuts, pretzels and snack mix. Your choice of Tri-Tip Sandwiches served with creamy horseradish, salsa, BBQ sauce and rolls or the Chili Bar served with red onions, cheddar cheese, sour cream, onion straws and cornbread pieces. Your choice of 2 salads from pasta salad, Caesar salad or seasonal fruit salad.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input_grouping_wrap">
                            <div>
                                <p>Entr&eacute;e (Choose One)</p>
                                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item 2" value="Tri-Tip Sandwiches"> Tri-Tip Sandwiches<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item 2" value="Nacho Station"> Chili Bar<br>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Salads (Choose Two)</p>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Salad Name 2" value="Pasta"> Pasta<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Salad Name 2" value="Ceasar"> Ceasar<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Salad Name 2" value="Seasonal Fruit Salad"> Seasonal Fruit Salad<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="delivery-time">
                                <p>Choose Delivery Time</p>
                                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 2" value="Pre Game">Pre Game<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 2" value="Kick Off">Kick Off<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 2" value="Half Time">Half Time<br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>How many?</p>
                            <input type="text" name="FIELD GOAL PACKAGE" value="0" maxlength="2" class="qty num-pallets-input" id="FIELD+GOAL+PACKAGE-mvp-num-pallets" style="margin-bottom:0" />
                            <p class="price-per-pallet"><small>* Price per guest: <span> 20.00</span></small></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-total">
                            <input type="text" class="row-total-input" id="FIELD+GOAL+PACKAGE-mvp-row-total" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but a few things pop out to my eye: a) `input[class='onlyTwo']` could be written as `input.onlyTwo` or even `.onlyTwo` since you don't appear to have any other elements with that class; b) since `checked` is a Boolean property, it's probably best to use `.prop("checked", false)`; c) You may want to use classes instead of partial matches against attribute values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use jQuery to get values of selected checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292778/use-jquery-to-get-values-of-selected-checkboxes)

Comment: I saw that post, but I don'w know how I would implement that on my code.

Comment: See where you have `var salad = pkg.find('[name^="Salad Name"]:checked');`? That will actually select multiple elements. So maybe rename it `salads` :). Then you can get an array of the values (there are answers in the duplicate which show how). Then, to get them as a comma-delimited list, just use `join(', ')` as shown in [Easy way to turn JavaScript array into comma-separated list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201724)

Comment: Heretic Monkey, how do I do that? I just stared learning JS, so i'm not sure how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: what is the caret for?

Comment: @awesomeguy to find all the inputs that start with Entree Item, Salad name, and Delivery time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem mentioned in your question. I added a for loop to loop through all the item in `salad`, which was actually an array. This is helpful when you have a vast selection.

There is one bug that you may need to fix yourself: If you choose all three salads the two-salad only message comes up but all three salads show up in the `#output`. The only reason could be is that the `summarizePackages()` function runs first and I tried to fix it but with no success.

Anyways, here is the code:

```js
function summarizePackages() {
            //get inside the div that's holding the buttons
            var packages = $('.expander-content > .item');
            var summary = '';

            packages.each(function(index, pkg) {
                pkg = $(pkg);

                var name = $.trim(pkg.find('h3').text());
                var entree = pkg.find('[name^="Entree Item"]:checked');
                var salad = pkg.find('[name^="Salad Name"]:checked');
                console.log(salad.length);
                var delivery = pkg.find('[name^="Delivery Time"]:checked');
                var hasOrder = pkg.find('input:checked').length > 0;

                if (hasOrder) {
                    summary += 'Name of package: <b>' + name + '</b>';
                    summary += '<br>';

                    if (entree.length) {
                        summary += 'Entree selected: <b>' + entree.val() + '</b>' + '<br>';
                    }
                    if (salad.length) {
                      summary += 'Salads selected: <b>'
                      for (var i = 0;i < salad.length;i++) {
                          if (salad.length > 1 && i === 0) {
                              summary += salad[i].value + " and ";
                            } else {
                              summary += salad[i].value + " ";
                            }
                        }
                        summary += '</b>' + '<br>';
                    }
                    if (delivery.length) {
                        summary += 'Delivery selected: <b>' + delivery.val() + '</b>' + '<br>';
                    }
                    summary += '--------------------';
                    summary += '<br>';
                }
            });

            return summary;
        }

        $('#reviewOrder input').on('change', function() {
            var summary = summarizePackages();
            $('#output').html(summary);
        });
        
        //make sure the user only selects two checkboxes
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $("input[class='onlyTwo']").change(function () {
            var maxAllowed = 2;
            var cnt = $("input[class='onlyTwo']:checked").length;
            if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
               $(this).removeAttr("checked")
               alert('You can only select ' + maxAllowed + ' salads!');
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Order Form</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="reviewOrder">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Suite Packages</legend>
            <h6 class="fieldset_description">Please choose your delivery time for each item.<br> 12 order minimum</h6>
            <div class="expander">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="expander-trigger expander-hidden">View Suite Packages</a>
                <div class="expander-content">
                    <div class="item">
                        <h3 class="product-title">FIRST DOWN PACKAGE<small> $15.50ea</small></h3>
                        <p>Includes: Peanuts and pretzels. Your choice of Mustang Dogs served with mustard, ketchup, white onions, relish and buns, or the Nacho Station served with grilled chicken, jalapenos, olives, onions, guacamole, sour cream and nacho cheese. Your choice of 2 salads from pasta salad, Caesar salad or seasonal fruit salad. Cookie and brownie platter.</p>
                        <div class="entreesGroup">
                            <div>
                                <p>Entr&eacute;e (Choose One)</p>
                                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item 1" value="Mustang Hot Dog"> Mustang Hot Dog<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item 1" value="Nacho Station"> Nacho Station<br>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Salads (Choose Two)</p>
                                <input class="onlyTwo" type="checkbox" name="Salad Name 1" value="Ceasar"> Ceasar<br>
                                <input class="onlyTwo" type="checkbox" name="Salad Name 1" value="Pasta"> Pasta <br>
                                <input class="onlyTwo" type="checkbox" name="Salad Name 1" value="Seasonal Fruit Salad"> Seasonal Fruit Salad<br>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Choose Delivery Time</p>
                                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 1" value="Pre Game">Pre Game<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 1" value="Kick Off">Kick Off<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 1" value="Half Time">Half Time<br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p>How many?</p>
                        <input type="text" name="FIRST DOWN PACKAGE" value="0" maxlength="2" class="qty num-pallets-input" id="FIRST+DOWN+PACKAGE-mvp-num-pallets" style="margin-bottom:0" />
                        <p class="price-per-pallet"><small>* Price per guest: <span> 15.50</span></small></p>
                        <div class="row-total">
                            <input type="text" class="row-total-input" id="FIRST+DOWN+PACKAGE-mvp-row-total" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div>
                            <h3 class="product-title">FIELD GOAL PACKAGE<small> $20.00ea</small></h3>
                            <p>Peanuts, pretzels and snack mix. Your choice of Tri-Tip Sandwiches served with creamy horseradish, salsa, BBQ sauce and rolls or the Chili Bar served with red onions, cheddar cheese, sour cream, onion straws and cornbread pieces. Your choice of 2 salads from pasta salad, Caesar salad or seasonal fruit salad.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input_grouping_wrap">
                            <div>
                                <p>Entr&eacute;e (Choose One)</p>
                                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item 2" value="Tri-Tip Sandwiches"> Tri-Tip Sandwiches<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item 2" value="Nacho Station"> Chili Bar<br>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Salads (Choose Two)</p>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Salad Name 2" value="Pasta"> Pasta<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Salad Name 2" value="Ceasar"> Ceasar<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Salad Name 2" value="Seasonal Fruit Salad"> Seasonal Fruit Salad<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="delivery-time">
                                <p>Choose Delivery Time</p>
                                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 2" value="Pre Game">Pre Game<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 2" value="Kick Off">Kick Off<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 2" value="Half Time">Half Time<br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>How many?</p>
                            <input type="text" name="FIELD GOAL PACKAGE" value="0" maxlength="2" class="qty num-pallets-input" id="FIELD+GOAL+PACKAGE-mvp-num-pallets" style="margin-bottom:0" />
                            <p class="price-per-pallet"><small>* Price per guest: <span> 20.00</span></small></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-total">
                            <input type="text" class="row-total-input" id="FIELD+GOAL+PACKAGE-mvp-row-total" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```