# get id of selected checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have a Table. In this table, the user can select all. or 3-4 records can be selected. What I need to do is to get the ids of the records he chose, but I couldn't do that.

HTML TABLE

```
 <table id="kisitListesi" class="table mb-0 table-center">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="border-bottom text-start py-3"><input  id="kisitselectall" type="checkbox" /> Tümünü Seç</th>
              <th class="border-bottom text-start py-3">Şirket</th>
              <th class="border-bottom text-start py-3">Kullanıcı</th>                                                              <th class="border-bottom text-start py-3">Kısıt</th>
               <th class="border-bottom text-center py-3">Diğer</th>
   </tr>
     </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach (var item in AdminStatic.stokKisitiOlanKullanicilar())
   {
         <tr class="shop-list">
        <td class="border-bottom text-start py-3"><input class="kisitsec" data-idd="@item.ID" type="checkbox" /></td>       <td>@AdminStatic.GetKullaniciIsletme(Convert.ToInt32(item.Isletme)).IsletmeAdi</td>
           <td>@item.AdSoyad</td>
   <td>@item.Kisit</td>
     <td class="text-center">
            <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-success">
          <a style="color:white; margin:auto;" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="KisitDuzenle(@item.ID">
       <i class="uil uil-edit"></i>
            </a>
          </span>
         <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">
      <a style="color:white; margin:auto;" href="javascript:void(0)"onclick="@item.ID">
                 X
        </a>
       </span>

    </td>
      </tr>
             }
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

JAVASCRİPT

```
 function seciliDatalar() {
            var result = [];
            $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function (item) {
                result.push($(".kisitsec").attr("data-idd"));
            });
            alert(result)
        }
```

Comment: Do you get an Error?

Comment: Normally, the id should be 2,3,4. always comes 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use jQuery to get values of selected checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292778/use-jquery-to-get-values-of-selected-checkboxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `$(".kisitsec")` always returns all of the elements that have the `.kisitsec` class and then `.attr("data-idd")` returns the attribute from the the *first* matched element.

What you want to do instead is to use the `this` context within your `each` loop to get the currently iterated element:

```
var result = [];
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
  result.push($(this).attr("data-idd"));
});
```

An alternative way to achieve the same thing is by using jQuery's [`.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and [`.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```
const result = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
  return $(this).attr("data-idd");
}).get();
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/w0jtyu39/) is an example fiddle.